# Create AWS IoT solution to filter incoming data and send response to Web App in real time

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, iot, aws-iot

[image: desired architecture]

I wish to achieve this architecture with AWS IoT services, where I have a group of IoT devices that send data to the cloud (AWS IoT Core), When the data comes to the cloud I want to do two things per message:

1. Archive the message into a db container, that will be queried by a backend to get this data and display them.
2. Apply a filter conditions code based on some attributes saved on my local db, <I can save these attributes on the cloud too .e.g. DynamoDB perhaps!>, Then based on the filter if the message's data violates a specific condition it should fire an alert (notification) and send it to the frontend to view.

How can I achieve this?

I made some research and found this solution https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/real-time-iot-device-monitoring-with-kinesis/ [image: AWS IoT Solution]

I know now that I can filter the stream data with AWS Kinesis data analytics application code, but how can I read my conditions from my local db within the application code? is this even supported? What's the alternative way to achieve my simple architecture shown above?

Please note that I'm beginner to AWS.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a much simpler architecture than the one you posted from AWS. You could simply trigger a single lambda function for each incoming message on your IoT topic. This lambda could store the function in the database and apply to filter to send a notification if possible.

If you really want to have the data locally on a local database, that will make the architecture much more complex (and much more expensive). So I would advise you to simply use DynamoDB to store the incoming data and to store the values you need to apply your filter.

Depending on the amount of data you expect, you can then evolve your architecture to use two lambdas (one for storage, one for notifications) and use an SNS-SQS fanout architecture for example.